# Messed up permissions of mail folders

Tags: permissions

i just messed up the permissions of all /var/spool/mail folder on a 250 user system. I have the homefolders with the correct permissions and the same name. Is there an easy way to make the permissions of the /var/spool/mail folders the same as the home folders?

Regards

Comment: please show is the structure of the subdirectories of /var/spool/mail?

Comment: It is /var/spool/mail/username like in /home/username. And I think the mail folders need to be owned by their user like the homefolder. I am trying to whip up a little script that copys the folder permissions. I messed up when moving /var/spool/mail with rsync without preserving permissions.

Comment: I nearly got it. I used chown --reference

Comment: That _heavily_ depends on your mail setup. If it is a virtual mail system, it might well be that some virtual user must own the mails. Please check that, first.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a script, if the home directories map to the mail directories something like this would work

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(find  /home -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec basename {} \; )
do
    echo "$user"
    # Do other things as required
done
```